# Find a reference to AppCompatDialogFragment

Tags: android, dialogfragment

In my Andriod app, I've got a Dialog extended from AppCompatDialogFragment. I show it immediatelly in my App's main Activity's onCreate:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedState)
  {
  super.onCreate(savedState);

  // ....

  if( savedState==null )
    {
    MyDialog diag = new MyDialog();
    diag.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), null);
    }
  }
```

later on I want to dismiss this dialog - so I need to find it. I cannot simply remember a reference to it in my Activity, as when I e.g. rotate the phone the Dialog gets recreated and my reference would be invalid.

How do I get a reference to MyDialog later on in my code?

Comment: `savedState` won't be `null` ...so why it should be recreated??

Comment: @MartinZeitler - fragments are automatically saved and restored. The `savedState==null` is necessary to ensure that it only is created once.

Comment: @ianhanniballake `onConfigurationChange()` it still won't enter that branch, because it won't be `null` then. Looking it up by tag-name appears solid, because it doesn't add any clutter, even when it is only a local variable. It might indeed be a difference, if it's about 1 dialog or about multiple ones, if keeping a reference to the instance or using fragment-tags suits better.

Comment: @MartinZeitler - you won't go through `onCreate()` at all if you're handling configuration changes manually. You'll *always* need to look up references to your fragments from FragmentManager since they'll *always* be recreated along with the activity - that's precisely what the `tag` is for. Really the only factor is whether you do that lookup in an `else` block for when `savedState != null` or if you do it on demand. In either case, it'll be the same code to find the fragment.

Comment: @ianhanniballake Does that mean, that an reference to the dialog's instance may change on `onConfigurationChange()`? If so, then looking up by tag-name seems to be the only possible solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second parameter to [show()](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/DialogFragment#show(androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager,%20java.lang.String)) is the `tag`.

This tag is what allows you to use [`findFragmentByTag()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentManager#findFragmentByTag(java.lang.String)) later to retrieve that Fragment.

Therefore, just use any other value than `null`

```
diag.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "dialog");
```

And then you can retrieve the fragment:

```
MyDialog diag = (MyDialog) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("dialog");
```